# How to be able to respond to a tap on a navigation item title?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I want to add a something like a UITapGesture when you tap at the title it goes to another controller. I think UITapGesture only works for UIView but I want it to be for a text(String).

```
@objc func checkIfUserIsLoggedIn(){
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        perform(#selector(viewController.handleLogout), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
    } else {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as?[String : AnyObject] {
                self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["Full Name"] as? String
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about tapping on the title in the nav item?

Comment: Yes I want to tap on the title to transfer me to another controller

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use the `titleView` property of `UINavigationItem` instead of `title`. Use a `UIButton` for the `titleView`.